# How to search/filter by unnest result?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to search/filter (case-insensitive) in the ARRAY(TEXT) (using PostgreSQL). While I found it was impossible directly, it was suggested that a solution with unnest could be used, so I started on that.

The table I'm using is the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
 
 
class CaseStudy(db.Model):  # type: ignore
    __tablename__ = "case_studies"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    solutions = db.Column(ARRAY(db.Text))
    ...
```

I could do something similar with pure SQL (minus the lower-case part):
`SELECT * FROM case_studies  WHERE 'a' IN (select(unnest(case_studies.solutions)));`

But I cannot convert it to SQLAlchemy. I think the closest I got was with
`result = session.query(cls.id).filter('a' in func.unnest(cls.solutions))`
(but I got `NotImplementedError: Operator 'contains' is not supported on this expression`)
or
`result = session.query(cls.id).filter("a" in select(func.unnest(cls.solutions)))`
but then I get `TypeError: argument of type 'Select' is not iterable`.

Any advice how to do this in SQLAlchemy? Also, how to convert unnest's results into lower-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the following:

```
result = session.query(cls.id).select_from(func.unnest(cls.solutions).alias("sols")).filter(column("sols").ilike(f"%a%"))
```

If anyone posts a better solution, I'll re-accept the answer.